# Unofficial Metacritic API — Chicken Coop

Tags: data-request, api, metadata, legal, games

My team and I are building a website about video games that has affiliate links in it.

My question is about the Chicken Coop API key provided by rapidapi (https://rapidapi.com/valkiki/api/chicken-coop/details).

Is using Chicken Coop API key breaking any Terms of Use of Metacritic? Are there any alternatives?

Main goal is to get metadata about video games from someone and Metacritic Game Metadata has all the video game details plus their Metascores. (If You know any free alternatives that offer video game metadata and allow for commercial use, please let me know).

Answer (score 0):

Metacritic ToS link forwards to

https://cbsinteractive.com/legal/cbsi/terms-of-use/

> *You are only permitted to access and view the Content for personal, non-commercial purposes in accordance with these Terms, and may not build a business or other enterprise utilizing any of the Content, whether for profit or not.*

(keep reading that section -  it gets even less "open")

---

To answer your questions

> *Is using Chicken Coop API key breaking any Terms of Use of Metacritic?*

Yes.

> *Are there any alternatives?*

No (unless you drop the need for the Metascores). You can start with [this question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/2120/1511)

Comment: > "No (unless you drop the need for the Metascores). You can start with this question or the film".

Unfortunately, this is for Movies, not Video games. Do you know any alternatives for Video Games?

Thanks for clarifying the rest of the stuff!

Comment: I should read more carefully. I've edited the answer